# roblox freemodel banscript doesn't work properly

Tags: roblox

How do I fix teh roblox freemodel banscript I found and make it ban players by their id?
I tried editing it bellow but it doesn't seem to work...

Code:

```
-- Simple banscript
local Players = game:FindService"Players" 
local banlist = {  
    "Roblox",
    "Builderman",
     4697369149  -- Doesn't work when I put id
}



local function onPlayerAdded(...)
    ({...})[#{...}][table.find(banlist,tostring(({...})[#{...}]))and banlist[#banlist]or "GetFullName"](({...})[#{...}])
end;banlist[#banlist+1]=Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)and
    ({coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function(...)
        return xpcall(coroutine.wrap(function(...)table.foreachi(...,onPlayerAdded)
        end),error,Players:players())and(({...})[#{...}])
    end),"Kick")})[2]
```

I tried editing it bellow but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Easiest solution would be to throw this away and write something new. It would certainly make figuring out what's wrong easier. All you need for a ban-script is the [Player:Kick(message)](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#Kick) function.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the ban-script that you shared is this : when a player joins the game, check if their name is in the `banlist` and if it is, kick them from the game when they join.

However, that script is a nightmare to read, it's either been through some kind of obfuscator, or the original author is a sadist. Some examples include :

- `({...})[#{...}]` = `{ player }[1]` = a needlessly complicated way to get the player
- `table.find(banlist,tostring(({...})[#{...}])) and banlist[#banlist] or "GetFullName"` = an insane way to access the function name `GetFullName`
- `({coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function(...) return xpcall(coroutine.wrap(function(...)table.foreachi(...,onPlayerAdded) end),error,Players:players())and(({...})[#{...}]) end),"Kick")})[2]` = `{some nonsense, "Kick"}[2]` = "Kick"

All of this code soup is just an elaborate way to call the [Player:Kick(message)](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#Kick) function. And a much more simple way to make that work is to keep a dictionary of [userids](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#UserId) along with the reason they were banned. And if you only know their username, you can use the [Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(name)](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetUserIdFromNameAsync) function to get their userId.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

-- create a message to show to banned users
local BAN_MESSAGE = "You have been banned from playing this game."

-- keep a dictionary of userIds of banned users, and the message to show them when they get kicked
local bannedUsers = {  
    [Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync("Roblox")] = BAN_MESSAGE,
    [Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync("Builderman")] = BAN_MESSAGE,
    [4697369149] = "The creator just doesn't like you very much",
}

-- listen for when a player joins the game
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- check if the newly joined player is not allowed to play the game
    local banReason = bannedUsers[player.UserId]
    if banReason then
        -- remove the banned user from the game
        player:Kick(banReason)
    end
end)
```